# Сохранение типа DateTime в БД PostgreSQL (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

**Доброго времени суток!**

Согласно официальной информации из вики по PostgreSQL точность хранения времени в базе составляет 1 microsecond.
Но .net хранит наносекунды (100 nanoseconds).
Из-за этого получается, что при сохранении типа данных DateTime в timespan (или просто в time) теряется 1 знак.

Если поиск данных с фильтрацией проводить непосредственно ОРМ, то есть шансы, что она сгладит данный факт и найдёт.
Но если сначала вытащить данные и затем искать, то разумеется ничего не найдём (т.к. начальные данные изменились).

Возникает вопрос, кто-то сталкивался с данной особенностью и как решал?

**Видятся следующие варианты решения проблемы:**

1. Хранить непосредственно тики (datetime -> long), но придётся каждый раз конвертировать из одного в другое + будет сложно писать запросы непосредственно в sql
2. Уменьшать точность временной метки самостоятельно в приложении (например при создании объекта сразу же указывать не DateTime.Now, а DateTime.Now / 1000 * 1000)
3. При поиске и сравнении добавлять погрешность

**Существуют ли более качественные решения проблемы?**

Comment: Позвольте полюбопытствовать, что является источником данных с такой меткой времени? Если метка времени присваивается операционной системой, то в зависимости от типа ОС в поисках баланса между временем отклика системы и ее производительностью, связанной с оптимизацией затрат на переключение контекста, минимальный квант времени выделяемый процессу может варьироваться (если в это не лезть) от 10-100мс. Тогда чего стоит такая точность метки времени при скажем шаге дискретизации 10мс и времени реакции определимой как удвоенное время шага 20мс?

Comment: Доводилось сталкиваться с подобными проблемами, когда точность времени в БД отличается от времени в используемом языке/платформе. Приходилось подстраиваться: округлять или отбрасывать часть. / Вообще рекомендуется использовать NodaTime для работы с Постгресом. Возможно, есть смысл посмотреть в эту сторону.